# How to convert multiple coordinates from DMS to decimal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I'm tryng to convert some coordinates from DMS to decimal.
For example from `S1639 W07157` to `-16.65, -71.95`
To achieve this I use the code found: [here](https://en.proft.me/2015/09/20/converting-latitude-and-longitude-decimal-values-p/) modified as below:

```
def dm2dd(direction, degrees, minutes):
    dd = round(float(degrees) + float(minutes)/60, 4);
    if direction == 'S' or direction == 'W':
        dd *= -1
    return dd

def dd2dm(deg):
    d = int(deg)
    md = abs(deg - d) * 60
    m = int(md)
    return d, m

def parse_dm(dm):
    parts = re.split('(\w)([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\s(\w)([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})', dm)
    lat = dm2dd(parts[1], parts[2], parts[3])
    lng = dm2dd(parts[4], parts[5], parts[6])
    return lat, lng
```

Using this functions I can convert a couple of coordinates (for example `S1639 W07157`) without any problem, but sometimes I need to convert a string where multiple "couple" can be found (for example `S1549 W07150 - S1632 W07148 - S1653 W07154 - S1647 W07204 - S1630 W07156 - S1549 W07150`).
How can I modify the code to get an output like:

```
-15.8167 -71.8333 -16.5333 -71.8 -16.8833 -71.9 -16.7833 -72.0667 -16.5 -71.9333 -15.8167 -71.8333
```

Answer (score 0):

Say this is your input:

```
in = 'S1549 W07150 - S1632 W07148 - S1653 W07154 - S1647 W07204 - S1630 W07156 - S1549 W07150'
```

Then you can split it on the `-` character:

```
coords = in.split('-')
```

and run your function on each set of coordinates:

```
for coord in coords:
  parse_dm(coord)
```